# Can I use same class name for different elements styles?

Tags: css

It acceptable to use same class name for different styled elements? For example:

```
table.dom {
    background-color: #F9FAFA;
    float: right;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 352px
}
th.dom {
    background-color: #8FA4AD;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border: #2C3A44;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 88px;
}
td.dom  {
    font-size: .7em;
    border-color: #313841;
    background-color: #F9FAFA;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 30px;
    }
```

I assume that if I call the 'dom' class for different elements, it will not cause conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine and you can have shared attributed inside .dom if you wish.

Edit although, you don't need to apply a class to all the elements, Once the table has a class you can target sub elements by:

```
table.dom th {
    /*Style info*/
}
table.dom td {
    /*Style info*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid that practice for readability and maintenance. It should work however you are relying on browser makers such as Microsoft to be consistent from one release to the next in areas that are not subjects of acid tests. Rule by rule the td.dom has more specificity than .dom meaning it should work. th.dom "should not" over right td.dom's rules.

The acid tested standards approach is

```
table.dom th {}
```

and results in more compact HTML and CSS.

Being acid tested means it's the browsers fault if it does not work, but you would be who gets to fix it either way.

Jquery and such all assume acid tested css structures.

UPDATE: If it does not work on some specific browsers that may open up a whole new gene of browser sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, however, what's the difference between doing so and just target tags in your selectors?

If you want to target a certain area of those tags, you can give them a container and target them like `.details th {...} .details td {...}`

If it's for semantics, you should just use different class names.
e.g. `.detail-header {...} .detail-value {...}`

Answer (score -1):

for as far as i know, it does not cause any conflict.

however, if you have another selector like so:

```
.dom {
  font-weight:bold;
  ...
}
```

the styles defined there are applied to all elements with classname `dom`

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely fine. It will not cause a conflict.